# Nozzle leaking PETG and blobs on first layer

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, petg

I have an Ender 3 V2 Printer and I can print in PLA with good quality and no issues. I am using a 0.8 mm Nozzle and my model prints fine in PLA.

I have now tried to use Pinuotu 1.75 mm PETG transparent red filament with recommended nozzle temperature "210-240 °C"

I am getting blobs on the first layer only when doing the inner section but not on the walls or brim.

The first issue which I'm assuming is related is the nozzle seems to leak filament after I pause the print so assuming this is a retraction issue?

I have tried printing at 210, 215 and 220 °C with a bed temperature of 60 °C. I have no bed adhesion issues and have tried adjusting my material type, retraction settings, cooling (0, 20 and 100 %) and print speed (40, 45 and 65 mm/s) all which don't seem to help.

I am using Cura as a slicer. I think this may be a retraction issue? I have lost count of how long I have spent trying to print with this material. The only modification to the printer is a direct drive extruder.

Image on bed is here:
[image: Image on bed]

Nozzle after printing here:
[image: Nozzle after printing]

Offbed result here:
[image: Offbed result]

Comment: Welcome Chris. Can you add a photo to point out which issues you have, perhaps share the model and the most important slicer settings you use? Also, it is much nicer to read if the title actually contains the main question you have.

Comment: Thanks for your question but we prefer the question to be self contained where possible. Linking to images outside SE are prone to die (as links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)) & will be rendered useless if the linked-to content disappears. Please update your question and embed the images. Thanks! The links don't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried it on a new roll of PETG, or on a freshly dried one? It would remove one variable.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Apologies about the title and manor of the question. I was not able to upload the image direct as the app did not seem to give me an option. The PETG roll is brand new straight out the packet. I have tried numerous slicer options but can't see a way to upload a file without external links.

Comment: I have now been able to include images.